# Release based tags

Tags: discussion, tags

While going through the tags I noticed "winter" and "winter13". I think that most will agree winter is not specific enough, and could be merged with winter13, but maybe we should look at this a bit wider.

In a short term, release names such as summer12, winter13 can be useful, but do we want them as tags ?

My opinion: As our content grows, and we progress in time, references to the release names will devaluate, and mean less and less to those browsing our questions & answers.
Who still knows what got added in spring10 or summer08 ? 
Yet I do think, with the fast release schedule of salesforce, and changes happening, some reference should be set to each question. Correct answers right now may no longer be valid with a future release, maybe not now, but possible in a year from now. 
As releases will stack up, the only reference future users will have is the stackexchange based "question posted Y-m-d ago", which is not enough. 
I would like to suggest we discuss encouraging the introduction of **api-25**, **api-26**, etc tags, and using them on every question.

I consider this the most correct way of naming releases, and it is also how they are referenced to in the sf documentation, does this look like a good approach ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like this approach, and definitely think we should be using the API version numbers for issues/questions which are specific to a particular release. If it turns out to not be all that useful we can always kill those tags off again later down the road.

Comment: started a wiki on it http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161/salesforce-releases

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach works when a question has clear dependence on a specific version, but I don't think we should mandate an api-* version tag for all questions as you propose.  There are lots of reasons why answers will change and could become inaccurate, and I think we're best off depending on comments and upvotes on the newer answers to elevate the most up-to-date information.

Comment: Agreed, doesnt mandate api tag for all questions, but for questions specific for a particular version, its better of to have api-ver instead of winter13 or summer12